# grub rescue> ls (hdX,msdosY) not working

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I had a windows update last night and now I cannot boot. I am running windows 10 and Ubuntu 10.04LTS on my Lenovo X230 Laptop.
I tried to fix the problem with the suggested solutions that I found on this platform but none of them are working. The problem is that my output looks like this:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

When I try to ls like this:

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos6)
error: unknown filesystem
```

Then I booted from USB a live distribution and installed the boot-repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Here is the .log:
http://paste2.org/fNbdjUkB

The strange think is that in the log is says:

```
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
```

even though I have Windows 10 ???

Any help would be appreciated!